# confusions about the concurrent marking phase in G1

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

can't understand why there are additional young GCS during the concurrent marking phase.

[the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/gctuning/garbage-first-g1-garbage-collector1.html#GUID-3A99AE6C-F80A-4565-A27C-B4AEDF5CDF71) said:

> While concurrent marking is running, other young-only pauses may occur, until the Remark pause (the first large orange circle), where G1 completes marking. Additional young-only garbage collections may occur until the Cleanup pause.

if a young-gc occur while region A is in concurrent marking phase, what would happen to region A ? would it be evacuated? if so, how dose gc threads process the next & prev bitmap and other data structures (RSet blablabla...) in region A ?